# Randomizing simulation in SUMO and driver behavior

Tags: sumo

Does ["--random"](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Randomness#Random_number_generation_.28RNG.29) parameter change the 'sigma' value for driver behavior? 
e.g. If it is set to 0.3 for a vehicle type in rou.xml, would it be changed to another value when randomizing?

If it is the case, is there a way to randomize other properties while keeping this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--random` does not affect sigma directly because sigma regulates how big the influence of randomness is, but not the random number generation itself. If you want to randomize vehicle (type) parameters and not only have little variances in behavior, have a look at https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Misc#createVehTypeDistributions.py